# SQL/MySQL Query Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help with this SQL Query. It is designed to retrieve names of students with the same S.S_level values as Jaci Walker, and have taken courses (CS.C_SE_id) with Jaci Walker in the BG building.

I am having trouble on line 7. I need to be able to ensure that the people have enrolled in the same course as Jaci Walker. I'm not sure about what to put in the WHERE statement for that section.

The database schema can be seen here: [image: databse schema]

```
SELECT S.S_Fname, S.S_LName
FROM Student S, Enrollment E, CourseSection CS, Location L
WHERE S.S_id = E.S_id
AND E.C_SE_ID = CS.C_SE_id
AND L.Loc_id = CS.Loc_ID
AND S.S_Level = (SELECT S.S_Level FROM Student S WHERE S.S_Fname = "Jaci" AND S.S_Lname = "Walker")
AND CS.C_SE_id = (SELECT CS.C_SE_id FROM CourseSection CS WHERE **?**)
AND L.Loc_id = (SELECT L.Blodg_code FROM Location L WHERE L.Blodg_code = "BG");
```

Comment: ...and your problem is?

Comment: Yeah, what seems to be your problem with the query? Any error messages or results?

Comment: AND L.Loc_id = (SELECT L.Blodg_code FROM Location L WHERE L.Blodg_code = "BG"); appears redundant as you can simply filter the results using AND L.Blodg_code = "BG" instead of what you have as that table is already joined in.

Comment: how about proper join syntax

Comment: @tftd I am confused of what to put on line 7 where the **?** is.

Comment: If you just leave that line out you will get multiple entries.  You might edit your question to identify what result you are trying to achieve.  What is the question you are asking of the data?

Comment: @DrewPierce that only makes it easier on people like us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using current SQL-syntax using JOIN conditions instead of using the WHERE clause to show relationships between tables.  This way, you get all your table associations done and can better visually confirm you have those elements configured... THEN, tack on the criteria you are looking for.

What I have done here is to just have a PreQuery (result alias "JaciClassesInBG" ) that gets all of Jaci's classes that were enrolled in and ONLY those for the building "BG" (which was added to the JOIN clause to the location table). The WHERE clause was only for Jaci.

From that result, I have a list of all classes that Jaci took.  I grabbed her ID, S_Level and C_SE_ID entries.

From that, just join back to the enrollment table of all other students based explicitly on the C_SE_ID that Jaci took (thus all students in that exact same class).  However, I've EXCLUDED (via AND NOT...) Jaci's student ID from the list... we know she took the class, we are looking for everyone ELSE.

Finally, join that result back to the students table based on the common enrollment.  Now, we can associate the common "S_LEVEL" criteria of Jaci to those students...

Now, you can get whatever details you want for display... in this case, I am grabbing each student, and what class they had in common with Jaci.  One student may have been in multiple classes.  This will show each.  If you only care about one instance, I would just change the top to...

select DISTINCT S2.S_FName, S2.S_LName...

```
SELECT
      JaciClassesInBG.Course_Code,
      JaciClassesInBG.Course_Name,
      S2.S_FName,
      S2.S_LName
   from 
      ( SELECT 
              S.ID,
              S.S_Level,
              CS.C_SE_ID,
              C.Course_Code,
              C.Course_Name
           FROM
              Student S
                 JOIN Enrollment E
                    ON S.S_id = E.S_id
                    JOIN CourseSection CS
                       ON E.C_SE_ID = CS.C_SE_id
                       JOIN Location L
                          ON L.Loc_id = CS.Loc_ID
                          AND L.Blodg_Code = "BG"
                    JOIN Course C
                       ON CS.Course_ID = C.Course_ID
           WHERE
                  S.S_Fname = "Jaci" 
              AND S.S_Lname = "Walker" ) JaciClassesInBG
      JOIN
         Enrollment E2
            ON JaciClassesInBG.C_SE_ID = E2.C_SE_ID
            AND NOT JaciClassesInBG.S_ID = E2.S_ID
            JOIN Students S2
               ON E2.S_ID = S2.S_ID
               AND JaciClassesInBG.S_Level = S2.S_Level
```

Answer (score 0):

IF I'm understanding the question right this should work:

```
SELECT s.S_Fname, s.S_LName
FROM Student s

INNER JOIN Enrollment e ON s.S_id = e.S_id
INNER JOIN CourseSection cs ON e.C_SE_ID = cs.C_SE_id
INNER JOIN Location l ON cs.Loc_ID = l.Loc_id

INNER JOIN Student s2 ON s.S_Level = s2.S_Level AND s2.S_Fname = "Jaci" AND s2.S_Lname = "Walker"
INNER JOIN Enrollment e2 ON s2.S_id = e2.S_id
INNER JOIN CourseSection cs2 ON e2.C_SE_ID = cs2.C_SE_id

WHERE l.Loc_id = l.Blodg_code = "BG"
AND cs.Course_ID = cs2.Course_ID
```

I'm unable to test at the moment and it was quickly done. Maybe a better solution can be found?

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I can't test it right now, but I'll do it in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the data I can't test but the following may help (the first inner select is pulling back all the relevant C_SE_ID's)

```
SELECT S.S_Fname, S.S_Lname
FROM Student S, Enrollment E
WHERE S.S_id = E.S_id
        AND E.C_SE_ID IN (SELECT CS.C_SE_ID
        FROM Student S2, Enrollment E2, CourseSection CS, Location L
        WHERE S2.S_id = E2.S_id
                AND E2.C_SE_ID = CS.C_SE_ID
                AND CS.Loc_id = L.Loc_id
                AND L.Blodg_code = 'BG'
                AND S2.S_Fname = 'Jaci'
                AND S2.S_Lname = 'Walker')
        AND S.S_Level = (SELECT S3.S_Level
        FROM Student S3
        WHERE S3.S_Fname = 'Jaci'
                AND S3.S_Lname = 'Walker')
        AND S.S_Fname <> 'Jaci'
        AND S.S_Lname <> 'Walker'
```

I would recommend using different aliases within inner queries (e.g. S2, E2) to avoid confusion.